# Bootstrap navbar not shrinking on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If i just shrink down the window in Chrome, the `navbar` will work as intended, but when i go into chrome's device emulator, the `navbar` never changes to the toggle button.

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top affix-top" style="border:0;background-color:transparent;position:absolute;">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 20px 15% 0;">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><img class="img-responsive" src="/logo.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">
                        <span>Rewards</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">
                        <span>Member Care</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">
                        <span>Sign Up</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll login-btn" href="#login-form">
                        Log In <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: check the inclusion of both bootstrap.min.js and jquery.js, here it works https://jsfiddle.net/Lj17f2bx/

Answer (score 4):

You could start by confirming you've set the viewport meta tag in the head of your page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I don't think it should be a comment. It's an answer, and it's the solution.

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct.  Thank you so much! I was dying for days on this problem.